# DRF one to many serialization -- AttributeError from missing field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Error:**

> AttributeError at /stats/matches
>
> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `players` on serializer `MatchSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Match` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'Match' object has no attribute 'players'.

---

**Models:**

Every `Match` has 10 players.

```
class Match(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, blank=True)
    mid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    mlength = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    win_rad = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Player(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    playerid = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='novalue')
    # There is also a Meta class that defines unique_together but its omitted for clarity.
```

---

**Serializers:**

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = "__all__"

class MatchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    players = PlayerSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = ("mid","players")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MatchSerializer` search for a `players` attribute in `Match`'s instance, but it couldn't find and you get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /stats/matches

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field players on 
serializer MatchSerializer. The serializer field might be named 
incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the Match instance. 
Original exception text was: 'Match' object has no attribute 'players'.
```

In DRF serializer, a parameter called source will tell explicitly where to look for the data. So, change your `MatchSerializer` as follow:

```
class MatchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    players = PlayerSerializer(many=True, source='player_set')
    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = ("mid", "players")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that **`Match`** model has not an attribute called **`players`**, remember that you are trying to get backwards relationship objects, so you need to use **`players_set`** as field as django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) says.

You could solve this in **Two Ways**
**1.** Adding a `source` parameter to the `PlayerSerializer`

```
class MatchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    players = PlayerSerializer(many=True, source='player_set')
    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = ("mid", "players")
```

**2.** Change the **lookup-field**

```
class MatchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    player_set = PlayerSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = ("mid","player_set")
```