# Representing the other side of a one-to-one relationship in a serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a one-to-one relationship set up between a User model, and a UserProfile model. The UserProfile model contains additional information about the user, and is created immediately after a User model saves. The OneToOne field is set on the UserProfile.

The serialized User data appears fine when I access any of the views concering the UserProfile, but I would also like the UserProfile data to appear on User views, and I was wondering how to specify this in the UserSerializer.

EDIT: I need the UserProfile data so that I can do an easy lookup on the UserProfile id to change information about the User. I will have the User id client side. Ideally, I'd like to look up the User with that id, find the UserProfile id (amongst other UserProfile data), so that I can then change the data for the UserProfile that is associated with the User.

Example: user 1 is authenticated. I gather some information following registration, so I call the view `/api/users/1/`, which tells me that the user profile with an id of 20 is associated with that user. I can then update that user profile with the new data. I can't always assume that user id 1 will be associated with user profile id 1.

EDIT 2: Solved this similar to Angela's answer like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_profile = UserProfileSerializer(source="userprofile")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id", 
            "username", 
            "email", 
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "groups",
            "user_profile"
        )
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id", 
            "username", 
            "email", 
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "groups"
        )

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            "user", 
            "current_city", 
            "current_country"
        )
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    avatar = models.FileField(
        upload_to="uploads", 
        blank=True
    )
    age = models.IntegerField(
        null=True
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    current_city = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, 
        blank=True
    )
    current_country = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, 
        blank=True
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to have the userprofile information available for viewing in the user serializer and also have user info in the user serializer, I would recommend you use the serializer source arguements as follows -

**Recommended Approach**

This is based on the assumption that when you update user profile, you dont want to update any info in the actual user model. You use the user endpoint to do that.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name',read_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.second_name',read_only=True)
    ......  #(other user fields you want to include)
    ......
    ......


   class Meta:
      model = UserProfile
      fields = (
        "first_name",
        "last_name", 
        "current_city", 
        "current_country",
        .......,  # any other user fields
        .......
      )

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_profile = UserProfileSerializer(partial=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
          "id", 
          "username", 
          "email", 
          "first_name",
          "last_name",
          "groups",
          "user_profile"
      )
```

This will give you a nested representation of the user_profile inside your user object, which will also have the source fields, but you can choose to ignore that.

**Another approach**

Otherwise if you really want nested structures in both the serializers, you can use different serializers, but not sure what your use case is for this.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
           "current_city", 
           "current_country",
            .......,  # any other user_profile only fields
            .......
       )

   class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       user_profile = UserProfileSerializer(partial=True, required=False)
      class Meta:
          model = User
             fields = (
                "id", 
                "username", 
                "email", 
                "first_name",
                "last_name",
                "groups",
                "user_profile"
          )

  class UserSerializerNew(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     class Meta:
        model = User
          fields = (
            "id", 
            "username", 
            "email", 
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "groups"
        )

class UserProfileSerializerNew(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user  = UserSerializerNew(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            "current_city", 
            "current_country",
            "user"
         )
```

Comment: but `User` data still needs to appear on `UserProfile`. With your current code, this is not possible since `UserSerializer` is declared after `UserProfileSerializer` what is your view about the same??

Comment: I have edited the code to include UserData on User Serializer. You would create a profile when you are creating a user object or after you have finished creating it. Not the other way round.

Comment: this statement `user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)`, woun't it raise an error since  `UserSerializer` is referenced before it is declared??

Comment: Yes, Duh! missed the obvious, I have updated my answer with another solution.

Comment: If I run this, the user profile information does not show up in the user view.

Comment: @HPJM  which approach are you trying? Both the approaches should allow viewing the userprofile within the user view.

Comment: Also can you elaborate on what is your use-case and when do you need to edit user information?

Answer (score 3):

I think, you should use ***Two `UserProfileSerializer`*** for this purpose as,

```
#serializer.py
class UserProfileSerializer_Temp(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            "user",
            "current_city",
            "current_country"
        )


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_profile = kwargs.pop('user_profile', True)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user_profile is False:
            self.fields.pop('user_profile', None)

    user_profile = UserProfileSerializer_Temp(source='userprofile_set')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            "username",
            "email",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "groups",
            "user_profile"
        )


class UserProfileSerializer_New(UserProfileSerializer_Temp):
    user = UserSerializer(user_profile=False)


#views.py

class UserProfileAPI(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer_New
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()


class UserAPI(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

**What's the relevence of `user_profile=False` ?**
It's act like a simple flag. If we do not pass something like that from `UserProfileSerializer_New`, it will serializer the **`UserProfile`** ***twice***. See this [Screenshot --- image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L0MX.png) 

**Cureent Response**
1 . [UserAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1grX.png)
2 . [UserProfileAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaesT.png)

Comment: Sure. This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: it's not my question sir.

Comment: Ehhh...Can you specify the difference of my answer from your *expected* output?

Comment: I mean I am not the owner of the question, therefore, I am not in a position to accept it. The question was asked by @HPJM

Comment: oh..oops :( My bad

Comment: Just for enquiry, what is the use of `source=user` in this example??

Comment: We are used `user_profile` as *field*. DRF will check for `user_profile` in `User`'s instance (ie, `user_instance.user_profile`). But, it won't find.

Comment: @EsirKings [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181868/drf-one-to-many-serialization-attributeerror-from-missing-field/)

Comment: Thanks, man for this. I had a similar issue and it has helped me.

Comment: Unfortunately when I run this I get an error: `AttributeError at /api/users/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'user_profile' on serializer 'UserSerializer'.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'User' instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'user'.`

Comment: Can you add the `UserProfile` model ?

Comment: @JPG Added. Also check out my edit...maybe I wasn't too clear in the beginning.

Comment: Change `source='user'` to `source='userprofile_set'`